# How can I get other content type data in current content type?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to put one condition in my template file of `contenttype1`. The condition is if `contentype2` contains a field value `X` then I want to print one block in `contentype1`. So how can I get `contenttype2` field values in `contenttype1` template file. 
 To get more clarity, with the `contentype2` fields I am creating a views block. I want to display that block in `contentytype1` template file. So I want to check a field condition of `contentype2`. If that field has any value then only I want to display that views block in `contenttype1` otherwise it should not display. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `contenttype2` could contain 100 nodes. So which one of the 100 needs to have field value x? There needs to be some sort of specific relationship, how are you liking `/node/1` of `contenttype1` with `/node/15` of `contenttype2`?

Comment: with the contentype2 I am creating a views block. I want to display that block in contentytype1 template file. So I want to check one field condition of contentype2. if that field has any value then only i want to display that block in contenttype1 otherwise it should not display..

Comment: What is the contenttype1 ? Is it also views? Can you please elaborate your question with what data is what. Because, your question do not talk abt anything about views, and that is the significant point. So, answerer can get better idea how data is designed so he/she can give better answer.

Comment: @Suraj How are you **linking** these 2 nodes? Are you using entity reference? Taxonomy term reference?

Comment: @No Sssweat I am not linking these two contenttypes. but I am using the views block in contentype1.

Comment: let me ask you this `contenttype1` has `node/1`, `node/2`, `node/3` and `contenttype2` has `node/4`, `node/5`, and `node/6`. So when you visit `node/1` which `contentype2` node should we check for field value x? check all of them `node/4`, `node/5`, and `node/6`? or is there specific relationship, `node/5`only?

Comment: @No Sssweat Thank you for your support. I want to check condition for all the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make `X` a taxonomy term.

1) Go to taxonomy and create a vocabulary (ex: Colors)

2) Inside Colors vocabulary, add terms. (ex: Red, Blue, Green, Yellow etc..)

3) Go to `contentype1` manage fields and add a new field of type: Taxonomy Term Reference. Then select the vocabulary (colors).

4) Now edit your `contentype1` nodes and give them a taxonomy term. Ex: Node 1 blue, Node 2 red, Node 3 blue, ...etc

5) Repeat steps 3) and 4) but with `contentype2` this time.

6) Create a block view of `contenttype2` (You will see it lists all the `contentype2` nodes)

7) Under Advanced, add Relationship of Terms of the node, checkmark Colors and checkmark require relationship.

8) Add a contextual filter of Taxonomy Term and for when filter is not available, set it up like this (using screenshot from another answer):

[image]

Once you add the contextual filter, your view preview will go blank, which is normal. Go to a `contentype1` node, where you placed the view block, and you should see `contenttype2` nodes that have the same taxonomy term as the current `contentype1` node that you're viewing.